# Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, kde-apps

I am about to upgrade from a Ubunbtu 16.04 installation with some extra KDE applications to Kubuntu 16.10. Is there anything that I should do first and what happens to my existing Unity and Gnome-based applications?

Comment: To prove my point, here's a question that was posted just now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865201/partial-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10-failed

Comment: The only point that question provides is that users won't handle all the details in half the questions done here. User mentions he ran a command suggested in a forum but don't actually mentions the original problem or what he did before running that command.