# Partial Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 failed

Tags: upgrade, 16.10

When I upgrade to 16.10 I get some errors and it failed to upgrade.
Then one of the forums suggested to do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get reboot
```

But on the second step (`install -f`), it errors out with the following error:

```
Setting up tomcat8 (8.0.37-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat8.config: 5: /etc/default/tomcat8: c: not found
dpkg: error processing package tomcat8 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat8
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somehow Tomcat8 installation is messed up and i cannot even remove tomcat8 or complete the upgrade.

Any future updates / upgrades are also failing.

Never had the problem with any earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: How *exactly* have you installed it?

Comment: I already had 15.10->16.04 and then upgraded to 16.10 .

Comment: I already had 15.10->16.04 and then upgraded to 16.10 .
During the upgrade it said that the upgrade failed , but the Help -> About shows 16.10
And updates (from the automatic updates) now fails.

Comment: Even while removing VirtualBox, it gives the tomcat8 error. 
I am at a point where i would reinstall Ubuntu, but would like to avoid the headache, if there is an easy solution to fix this error.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to reinstall Tomcat8 - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04 also applicable to 16.10 - and/or run `sudo apt install -f` ... What does Virtuabox has to do with it?

Comment: Also upgrades between releases are usually safe provided it's already fully (`apt full-upgrade` / `apt-get dist-upgrade` (prior to 16.04)) updated and there aren't third-party software/sources and/or proprietary drivers involved... Otherwise is hit and miss, often miss. The "upgrade failed" message is to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. The file /etc/default/tomcat8 was corrupted.
It had some junk characters. I removed the erroneous characters and fixed the file and removed tomcat8 entirely and reinstalled tomcat8 successfully.

Even installing VirtualBox (which failed earlier due to tomcat8 errors) was successfull.

Thanks everyone for your help.